# Join two data frames using the data.table package in R based on dates that are within +/- 3 months

Tags: r, join, data.table, lubridate

I am trying to join two data frames; by ID, using the data.table package in R, as well as the lubridate package for dates. I only want to join rows with a Date2 that is 3 months prior or after the Date1

df1

| ID | Date1 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-09-09 |
| 2 | 2019-09-09 |
| 3 | 2019-09-09 |
| 4 | 2019-09-09 |

Df2

| Id | Date 2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2020-09-09 | 6 |
| 1 | 2019-10-09 | 7 |
| 2 | 2019-03-13 | 8 |
| 4 | 2019-10-27 | 15 |

Final data frame that I want

| ID | Date1 | Id | Date 2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-09-09 | 1 | 2020-09-09 | 6 |
| 2 | 2019-09-09 | 2 | NA | NA |
| 3 | 2019-09-09 | NA | NA | NA |
| 4 | 2019-09-09 | 4 | 2019-10-27 | 15 |

I have included my code below. I am getting error saying the = after roll is not needed, but I think it is needed.

````
library(data.table)
library(lubridate)

df1 <- data.table(ID = seq_len(4L),
                  Date1 = as.Date("2019-09-09"))

df2 <- data.table(Id = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 4L),
                  Date2 = as.Date(c("2020-09-09","2019-10-09","2019-03-13","2019-10-27")),
                  Value = c(6L, 7L, 8L, 15L))


df2[, Date1Copy := Date2]  
df2[, IDcopy := Id] 
setkey(df2, ID, Date2)    ## set the column to perform the join on
setkey(df, ID, Date1) 
test = df1[df2, rollends = if (roll=="nearest") c(TRUE,TRUE)
           else if (roll = as.Date(Date1)%m+% months(3)|roll = as.Date(Date1)%m-% months(3)) c(FALSE,TRUE)
           else c(TRUE,FALSE)]```
````

Comment: In second row of your result table, should `Id=2`? It seems like if you were only joining rows that fell within the time window, `Id` for that record would be `NA`

Comment: why not a non-equi join?

Comment: @chinsoon12  I thought about the non-equi join approach, but I couldn’t figure out a way to select the “nearest” record for each`ID` (any simpler than the method I proposed). Do you see a way to implement both the “nearest” selection and cross-table Date comparison in a single join statement?

Comment: @MattSummersgill I thought OP wasn’t asking for nearest. But it’s prob possible with by=.EACHI but prob slower than chainlinking []

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rolling joins in `data.table` are extremely useful but can be a little bit tough to get the hang of. The syntax for `rollends` is quite a bit different than what you've got there, it's not designed to handle any kind of complex logic, just simple a `TRUE`/`FALSE` case.

At any rate, here's one way to approach this problem. Using month arithmetic as a filtering criteria in combination with the `nearest` value requirement makes this a multi-step problem instead of a one-step join *(at least any way I can see it)*.

While the join/filter/copy result values operation is technically a one-liner, I did my best to add in plenty of explanation of the nested operations.

```
## Make a copy of Date2 to use as key, as it will be inaccessible within the joined table
df2[, Date2Copy := Date2]

## Set Keys
setkey(df1,ID,Date1)
setkey(df2,Id,Date2Copy)

## Step 3: (read the inner nested steps first!)
## After performing the steps 1/2, join the intermediate result table back to `df1`...
df1[
  ## Step 1:
  ## First use the key of `df1` to subset `df2`` with a rolling join
  df2[df1,.(ID, Date1, Date2), roll = "nearest"
      ## Step 2:
      ## Then apply the +/- 3 month filtering critera
      ][between(Date2,
                Date1 %m-% months(3),
                Date1 %m+% months(3))]
  ## Step 3:
  ## ...on the `ID` column and add the intermediate results
  ## for `Date2` and `Value` columns to `df1` by reference
  , c("Date2","Value") := .(i.Date2,i.Value), on = .(ID)]
     
## Results    
print(df1)
#    ID      Date1      Date2 Value
# 1:  1 2019-09-09 2019-10-09     7
# 2:  2 2019-09-09       <NA>    NA
# 3:  3 2019-09-09       <NA>    NA
# 4:  4 2019-09-09 2019-10-27    15
```

These are my three go-to resources (other than the package documentation) for rolling joins, they've all helped me understand some of the quirks at multiple points over the years.

- https://r-norberg.blogspot.com/2016/06/understanding-datatable-rolling-joins.html
- https://www.gormanalysis.com/blog/r-data-table-rolling-joins/
- http://franknarf1.github.io/r-tutorial/_book/tables.html#tables